# Find directories and create new sub directory inside each directory found

Tags: find

I need to insert a file in a new subdirectory that I will create when the `find` command is executed.

```
# find /home/user*/.dir/anotherdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "*.default" 
anotherdir/dwwcop9o.default
anotherdir/dge77smm.default
```

In each of the above "find" results I need to create subdir so that the directory structure would look like below:

```
anotherdir/dwwcop9o.default/subdir
anotherdir/dge77smm.default/subdir
```

Finally, after creating subdir above, I need to insert a file inside of the subdir.

How do I do this using `xargs`, `-exec` or `-execdir`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to solve this, see below.

```
# find /home/user*/.dir/anotherdir -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "*.default" -exec mkdir {}/anotherdir \; -exec cp newfile {}/anotherdir \;
```

N.B.

newfile must be in your current working directory, if not, define its absolute path.